# GVim Command / Script to delete lines from a set of 4

Tags: unix, vim

This post could count as duplicate , but i have not found any relevant answer in previous threads. I have a large (6 GB) text file and i wish to remove every 3rd and 4th line in a set of 4 lines . For example , the following

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
```

needs to be converted to this

```
line1
line2
line5
line6
```

Is there any vim script / command to remove those lines ? It could be also in multiple passes . 1 pass to delete the 3rd lines (in a set of 4 (line1,line2,line3,line4)) and another pass to delete again the 3rd lines (previously 4th ones , in a set of 3 (line1,line2,line3)) .

The commands `:g/^/+1 d3` is close to what i want but it also removes the second lines .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can also use Awk.

```
awk 'NR%4==3||NR%4==0{next;}1' file.txt > output.txt
```

To do this via Vim:

```
%!awk 'NR\%4==3||NR\%4==0{next;}1'
```

Comment: A very efficient solution and quite fast as well . It works exactly as intended and it also preserves the original file for comparison reasons (a bonus) . Minimal use of RAM and it demands just a single pass. So , my most preferred answer .

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU `sed`, you can filter the buffer through this pipeline:

```
sed -e '0~4d' | sed '0~3d'
```

The first `sed` deletes every 4th line, the second deletes every 3rd line.
This has the desired effect.

To pipe the current buffer through this command, enter this in command mode:

```
%!sed -e '0~4d' | sed '0~3d'
```

The `%` selects the *range of lines* to pass to a command (`%` means all lines, the entire buffer), and `!cmd` is the command to pipe through.

To perform this outside of `vim`, run these two steps:

```
sed -ie '0~4d' file
sed -ie '0~3d' file
```

This will modify the file, in two steps.

Comment: It works as intended . But because the answer of @Peter demands a single pass , i will go with his implementation .

Comment: @Lolidas the advantage of this solution with `sed` is when used outside of Vim (in a script, for example), and when it's desired to work in-place, without creating an extra file. It's up to you to choose the solution that better suits your need.

Comment: although not the best accepted solution for the particular problem , your answer also gave me an insight in sed and more specifically in character  replacing using sed on the same file , which was the second step of my work , so i also wanted to select the answer as best , but objectively couldnt .

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** It is a bad approach for large files, it needs ~3 sec for a 6MB file to perform a substitution.

---

This approach works in vim. Using regular expression, you find 4 lines and substitute them with first two lines of these 4. Works for a long file as well. Doesn't work for last 1–3 lines if there is a remainder of division of total lines number by 4.

`:%s#\(^.*\n^.*\)\n^.*\n^.*\n#\1\r#g`

Explanation:

`:%s` — substitute in the whole file, `#` used as a delimiter

`\(^.*\n^.*\)` — `\(\)` select two lines that will be used later as `\1`; `\n` stands for linebreak; `^` for the beginning of the line; `.*` for any symbol repeated as much times as possible before the linebreak

`\n` —  linebreak after the second line

`^.*\n^.*\n` — next two lines to be deleted

`\1\r` — substitute for lines with first two lines and add a linebreak `\r`

`g` — apply to the whole file

[image: Remove each 3rd and 4th lines]